# TextBox Alignment When Printing From UWP

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to print a page of text from a UWP app, but I'm having a problem with alignment. First of all, I've created a Page which contains the following xaml:

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <TextBlock Text="Welcome Printed World!" FontSize="36" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Notice how the TextBlock is aligned to be centered within the grid.

Then, I print it using the various PrintDocument event handlers; this the code to print preview it (simplified to ignore margins and the non-printable area):

```
Page printPage;

private void OnPrintDocumentPaginate(object sender, PaginateEventArgs e)
{
    // Construct an instance of the page to print, and tell Windows that there is only 1 page
    this.printPage = new PrintPage();

    printDocument.SetPreviewPageCount(1, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
}

private void OnPrintDocumentGetPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
{
    // Give Windows a reference to the page to print for preview
    this.printDocument.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, this.printPage);
}
```

And this is how it prints:

[image]

Notice that the TextBlock is not centered.

However, if I wrap the TextBlock in a border, like this:

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Welcome Printed World!" FontSize="36" Foreground="Black"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Then it is fine:

[image]

Can anybody see why the TextBlock is not centred when using the original xaml?

Comment: Give vertical alignment and horizontal alignment to center for grid also.

Comment: That worked, but then I have a problem if I want other TextBlocks aligned in other places, e.g in the bottom right corner, so I think the grid needs to fill the page. What I have found is that I can use a TextBox instead of a TextBlock, with a BorderThickess of 0 so it's just text on the printed page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same problem when upgrading from Windows 8.1 to UWP project.

When printing in UWP, the **TextBlock.VerticalAlignment** and **TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment** properties do not work as expected.

However, if you use a **Run** element instead of the **TextBlock.Text** property, they appear to work as expected:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="36" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Run Text="Welcome Printed World!" />
</TextBlock>
```

Alternatively you can use **TextBlock.Margin** for vertical alignment and **TextBlock.TextAlignment** for horizontal alignment.